# Dynamically removing and attaching the border on a nswindow

Tags: cocoa, border, nswindow

How do I go about adding/removing the window border after it has been created? the window was already designed in interface builder and I would prefer to avoid writing the window purely in code as I am still a long ways before i can say i am experienced with objective-c/cocoa.

Example Program:
a single window with the border initially, a button on it. If you click the button once it makes the boarder disappear and if you click it again then the boarder reappears.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't.  You might be able to fake it by taking the content view out of one window and making it be the content view of another window.